# Is there a connection between bathtub drains and tornados?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex, weather

In the MIT fluid videos ([link with timestamp](https://youtu.be/DCZgrRKKJjY?t=1362)), I heard that a tornado is essentially the same physics as a bathtub drain, but upside down. It doesn't look that way to me. It looks like both fluids have the same shape, and only the flow is reversed. From the narrators description, I would have thought a hurricane gets more narrow as elevation increases. But, it looks like the opposite is true.

What exactly is the connection between the flow going down a drain and the flow going up a hurricane? Why isn't a hurricane the mirror image of a bathtub drain?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: [Whirlpools and Tornados](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56388/206691). The answer by @handofkwll says "One important difference between whirlpools and tornadoes is that the water drains out of the bottom of a whirlpool while tornado air drains upward through the low pressure centre of the vortex." That's probably what the MIT video means by "upside down."

Comment: The thing is, I would expect the "end" of the drain to be the shortest bit, but the end of the tornado is the longest piece.