# What allows this tornado to form in a frying pan?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, vortex, weather

I have just seen this video here where a mini tornado has formed in a frying pan:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CJ-8ze2FjE

Does anyone know how this happens or where I can find an explanation?

Comment: It looks like a tornado, but a tornado carries energy , while this vortex takes energy from the heated pan.

Comment: You could look at [tornado machines](https://www.google.com/search?q=tornado+machine&client=ubuntu&hs=RZv&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch). They usually have air inlets that create a circulation around the axis. The window may play that role, although, in my experience, it needs to be quite symmetrical about the axis.

Answer (score 1):

The window on one side is open providing an asymmetric air supply, and you can hear what sounds like a loud overhead extractor fan running. With the hot pan providing a source of rising smokey hot air, these are great conditions for producing an indoor tornado.

The window appears to be cracked open, forming a vertical slit (off-camera to the left) letting air into the kitchen very close to the pan. As Mike Dunleavy noted in his answer to a [Whirlpools and Tornados question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56451/145491), "Tornadoes happen when angular momentum of air is concentrated sufficiently in a vortex vertical to the ground." The window slit here provides a slightly off-center air supply that has non-zero angular momentum relative to the hot air rising from the pan. Just like a [figure skater spinning faster as they draw in their arms and leg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jeB4aAVQMug), angular momentum conservation makes the air spin faster as it is drawn into the vortex core.

For examples of how simply having an asymmetric vertical-slit air supply can turn hot rising air into a tornado, check out [Best Fire Tornado - DIY - no moving parts!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BxQd6AGYiI) and [How to build a DIY Dry ice tornado! - Fluid dynamics in a vortex!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qW7boSIgmY).  An overhead fan also helps to increase and concentrate the vertical air flow, as shown in [How To Make An Indoor Tornado In 3 Easy Steps!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNC-sClKROo).

Comment: Yep, open window + heat + pan parabolic shape in orchestration made this vortex. I believe if pan would be flat then hot air could not have enough time to spin-up in a pan, it would escape sooner from the pan without forming high vortex (or it would be a lot smaller).